# Django Apache only show It's works page

Tags: python, django, apache

I just learned Django and was able to create a simple web app. I am trying to deploy Django App in VPS with Debian 7.0. I am using Python 2.7, Apache 2, libapache2-mod-wsgi and Django 1.11.2. All went well until I accessed the domain server and only displayed the "It's works" page.

This is 000-default.conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName serverededenid-to.cloud.revoluz.io
ServerAdmin webmaster@serverededenid-to.cloud.revoluz.io

Alias /static /var/www/static-root
<Directory /var/www/static-root>
   Require all granted
 </Directory>

Alias /media /var/www/media-root
<Directory /var/www/media-root>
   Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/venv/src/cfehome>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>

WSGIDaemonProcess cfehome python-path=/var/www/venv/src/:/var/www/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
WSGIProcessGroup cfehome 
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/venv/src/cfehome/wsgi.py


ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Here is my urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Here is my settings.py:

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '9uy#-g_rmn^)&p@cc9-*37srhw7h0fiyv*2*=x@mels3qw+gzg'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['serverededenid-to.cloud.revoluz.io', '10.10.26.236']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'cfehome.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'cfehome.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/var/www/static-root/'
MEDIA_ROOT = '/var/www/media-root/'
```

Any body can help me?

Comment: What does your toplevel urls.py look like?

Comment: just for django admin.

Comment: Does the admin page work?

Comment: Admin url return 404 The requested URL /admin was not found on this server.

Comment: could you edit your answer and paste your urls.py?

Comment: Even if I set DEBUG = True and ALLOWED_HOSTS = [], I do not get any error messages.

Comment: See my edit below.

Answer (score 0):

Try emptying your urls.py and adding these:

```
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
```

where 'index' is your index view.